# MySQL conditional search query

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, sql-search

I am trying to get all the co-authors of an author. The first column is the id of a publication. The next three columns are the first, middle and last names of an author.

```
4 KARL K KWON
4 JACK A SMITH  
4 DINESH  SMITH  
5 KARL K KWON
5 JACK B SMITH
6 AMEY SCHENCK BAILEY
6 KARL K KWON
6 DINESH  SMITH
6 JACK  SMITH
13 JACK  SMITH
13 RONALD  VALE
```

I would like to get the following output

```
JACK A SMITH {DINESH SMITH, KARL K KWON}
JACK B SMITH {KARL K KWON}
JACK  SMITH {AMEY SCHENCK, KARL K KWON, DINESH SMITH, RONALD  VALE}
```

I am unable to understand which structure to use to store this new data and how to obtain it. Any suggestions/ideas...

**Edit**

This is not a simple group by publication id. For example, JACK SMITH has 2 publications here with ids 6 and 13. So the coauthors of both these publications need to be found and added to our set of co-authors for JACK SMITH.

Comment: It seems like, you can get the result by grouping publication id

Comment: Is there a particular reason why Jack comes first in your list?

Comment: @McAdam331 This is sample mock data - not exact data from the database

Comment: @Shafeeq Please see my edit above

Comment: Still not clear. Karl Kwon has two publications, why is he not separated?

Comment: @McAdam331 I do not understand what you mean by separated? The output which is displayed is sample output which needs to be computed for all authors.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the same format, but will it do?

**Edit**  Try #2:

Add these indexes:

```
INDEX(pub_id, name)
INDEX(name, pub_id)
```

This is the query, I think this self-join should do the trick:

```
SELECT  a.name AS Author,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS Co_authors
    FROM  ( SELECT  DISTINCT name FROM  tbl ) AS a  -- Get the authors
    JOIN  tbl b ON (b.name = a.name)                -- Get what they published
    JOIN  tbl c ON (c.pub_id = b.pub_id)            -- Get the co-authors
    GROUP BY  a.name;
```

Comment: Please see my edit above. Hope that makes the question more clear.

Comment: Where did ADAM SMITH come from?

Answer (score 0):

This will return ids and comma separated list of authors

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', firstName, middleName, lastName)) FROM table GROUP BY id
```

Join the table with the one above

```
SELECT t.*, tGrouped.authors  FROM table t
JOIN (SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ', firstName, middleName, lastName)) as authors FROM table GROUP BY id) tGrouped ON t.id=tGrouped.id
```

Finally, if you do not want a name to appear within authors list - use simple `REPLACE()`